# Proof that $\mathbb{R} \not\sim \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have troubles understanding the proof that $\mathbb{R} \not\sim \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ (that is, $|\mathbb{R}| \neq |\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}|$) where $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The proof we did in the class is very messy and not well structured so I can't even comprehend basic ideas. We used the fact that $\mathbb{R} \sim [0, 1]$.

This proposition proves that there are "biggers" infinities than others, which is quite surprising!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are at least as many functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as there are functions $\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$. Every function $\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$ corresponds to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and vice versa. So the statement can be proven by showing that $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality lower than its power set. And that is the well known Cantor's theorem.

Comment: $|\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}|\ge |\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{R}}|=|\mathcal P(\Bbb R)|>|\mathbb{R}|$ by [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cardinality of the set of all real functions of real variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17914/cardinality-of-the-set-of-all-real-functions-of-real-variable) (it was the 2011 target of this 2018 duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3009704).

Comment: How is $[0, 1]^{\mathbb{R}}$ power set of $\mathbb{R}$? Is this because for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exist a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, 1]$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41006/how-to-show-equinumerosity-of-the-powerset-of-a-and-the-set-of-functions-from. But first, beware we both wrote $\{0,1\}$ (the pair), not $[0,1]$ (the interval).

Comment: This post should be closed, as an exact duplicate of [The set of real numbers and the set of Real valued functions are not similar (equinumerous)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/949016).

Comment: So, codomain of every $f \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is a set of ordered pairs $(a, 0)$ and $(b, 1)$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, so we get this binary relation (0 = "don't include", 1 = "include") which in turn makes bijection between $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. Minimalistic and beautiful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a direct proof that $|\mathbb{R}| < |\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}|$, more precisely, that there is no surjection $s : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.

Consider any function $s : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$. We now define the function $d : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $d(x) = s(x)(x) + 1$, and claim that $d$ is not in the range of $d$. Assume otherwise. Then there is some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $s(y) = d$. But then we'd conclude that $d(y) = s(y)(y) + 1 = d(y) + 1$, contradiction.

Comment: This answer can be deleted, as an exact duplicate of [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/949849/386889).

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the proof we have done, but not as structured (not even close).